# not able to format the javascript code using ctrl+k+d in vs 2008

Tags: asp.net

I am not able to format/align the javascript code using ctrl+K+D in vs 2008. Am i missing some setting?

PLease let me know what should i do inorder to make this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have SP1 of VS 2008 installed. Formatting for javascript was added with it.

See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/archive/2008/08/13/visual-studio-2008-sp1-adds-javascript-formatting.aspx) blog post.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing i've come across that stops this from working is when there is an error somewhere in the javascript.  seems like a silly answer, but its all i've got.

Answer (score 0):

The menu option is Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document.  On my system this is mapped to Ctrl+E, then D.

If that doesn't work, you should check your Errors window for problems with the Javascript code itself.